# Simple Matrix inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $A, B$ be two $n \times n$ matrices.

It is known that $(A-B)(A-B)^*\leq 2(AA^*+BB^*)$

How about the lower bound in terms of $AA^*$ and $BB^*$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to obtain a lower bound by completing square. Pick any $\beta\ge0$ to obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\quad\frac{1}{1+\beta}AA^\ast-AB^\ast-BA^\ast+(1+\beta)BB^\ast\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\beta}}A-\sqrt{1+\beta}B\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\beta}}A-\sqrt{1+\beta}B\right)^\ast\\
&\ge0
\end{aligned}
$$
and hence
$$
(A-B)(A-B)^\ast\ge\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}AA^\ast-\beta BB^\ast.
$$

Comment: It seems that inequality is wrong for the case when $A=B$.

Comment: @volond  then $0 \geq \frac{- \beta^2}{1+\beta}  A A^\ast $