# Lower bound in matrix inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $A,B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices.
It is known (see [Simple Matrix inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494690/simple-matrix-inequality)) that for $\beta\geq0$

$$
\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}AA^\ast-\beta BB^\ast\leq (A-B)(A-B)^\ast\leq 2(AA^*+BB^*).
$$

What would be  the lower bound of the $p$-th Shatten norm
$$
\|(A-B)(A-B)^\ast\|_{S_{p/2}}^{1/2}
$$
in terms of Shatten norm of $\|(AA^*+BB^*)\|_{S_q}$, for any possibility of $q$?

So far, I have obtained the following: For any $\beta\geq 0$, we have
$$
(A-B)(A-B)^\ast\geq \frac{\beta}{1+\beta}AA^*-\beta BB^*.
$$

We can write that

$$
\|(A-B)(A-B)^\ast\|_{S_{p/2}}^{1/2}\geq \|\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}AA^*-\beta BB^*\|_{S_{p/2}}^{1/2}\\
=\|\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}(AA^*+BB^*)-\frac{2\beta+\beta^2}{1+\beta} BB^*\|_{S_{p/2}}^{1/2}
$$
Since for $x\geq y\geq0$, we have $\sqrt{x-y}\geq \sqrt x-\sqrt y$, we get that above line is
$$
\geq \|\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}(AA^*+BB^*)\|_{S_{p/2}}^{1/2}- \|\frac{2\beta+\beta^2}{1+\beta} BB^*\|_{S_{p/2}}^{1/2}\\
\geq \left(\sqrt{\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}}-\sqrt{\frac{2\beta+\beta^2}{1+\beta}}\right)\|(AA^*+BB^*)^{1/2}\|_{S_{p}}
$$
However, the coefficient in front of the norm is negative. So, one would just use a simple bound that $\|(AA^*+BB^*)\|_{S_q}\geq 0$ in this case.

Comment: Purely in terms of $AA^\ast+BB^\ast$, I think the only possible lower bound is zero, because $(A-B)(A-B)^\ast=0$ when $A=B$ but $AA^\ast+BB^\ast\ne0$ when one of $A$ or $B$ is nonzero.

Comment: @RamenNii-chan: Would something like that make sense? (please see edit in the question). You can play with $\beta$ coefficient.

Comment: How do you get what follows "Therefore"?

Comment: I am just taking now norm on both sides of the matrix inequality

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. In general, one may safely infer $\|X\|\le\|Y\|$ from $X\le Y$ only when $X$ is PSD, but in your case, $\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}AA^\ast-\beta BB^\ast$ is not always PSD. As I wrote before, since it can happen that $(A-B)(A-B)^\ast=0$ but $AA^\ast+BB^\ast$ is nonzero, the only possible lower bound for the norm of the former in terms of the norm of the latter is zero.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you very much.